# WSL: Windows doesn't have permission to write new user files

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with WSL2 and created a new user with sudo privileges:

```
sudo adduser newuser
sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser
su - newuser
```

Windows does not seem to have permission to write in the new user folder. Here with Visual Studio Code:

```
touch test.txt
code test.txt
```

and then writing something and trying to save will ask me to try and do it as admin, which I do and then get this error message:

```
Failed to save 'test.txt': 
Command failed: "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-pdtmzg" "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\newuser\test.txt"
Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\newuser\test.txt'
```

Here is the result of `ls -all` with the new user `work`:
[image]

Here is the result of `ls -all` with the default user `hellmers`:
[image]

Here are the groups for the users. I also tried adding `work` to the `hellmers` group:
[image]
[image]

The only way I manage to get it to work is to give `others` write privileges through `sudo chmod o+w <file>`, which shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: Why have you chosen to submit the same exact question to 3 different communities? Cross posting isn’t allowed

Comment: Please provide a “ls -all” for the folder containing the file in question.  Your cross posts are the only search results I could find for that permission issue, which is one of the reasons, cross posting is extremely discourage

Comment: @Ramhound As several forums seemed relevant for this question. Also a bit in a hurry, not being able to wait 2 days on each forum because I have posted in the wrong one. I have the plan to remove the others as I would see which were the most relevant. That is, I am about to remove the others now.

Comment: Super User and Ask Ubuntu are not forums.  You being in a hurry, does not change the fact, cross posting your question is highly discouraged and actually works against you. So the reason you are unable to modify test.txt is due to the permission, everyone only had read permissions, and by running the command you are running the way you are running it you are not running it as the a user in the group that owns the file nor are you the user who owns it.  Have you defined the default user to be whatever user is in the `work` group?

Comment: @Ramhound `work` is actually the new user I created. And I created the file `test.txt` with that user. I have the default user and the `work` user which I put in the sudo group. Not sure what to do

Comment: Change the permissions to 777 and see if the command will work.  I asked specifically, if the default user, is in the work group.  You have simply indicate you have a default user, which I am going to guess, is NOT the `work` user.

Comment: "The only way I manage to get it to work is to give others write privileges through sudo chmod o+w <file>, which shouldn't be necessary?" - It is when Visual Studio Code is not being run by the owner of the file.

Comment: @Ramhound Hey, it is pretty obvious I am not totally sure about all of this. Please have that in mind. I updated the question with the `other` write privileges just before you wrote that

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, then it might be how VS code is being ran when writing `code` with the new user?

Comment: Set the default user to `work` or change the group of the default user to the same group as `work` or change the permission on the file to `-rw-rw-rw-`.  I can't really submit an answer if I don't know what the username for the default user is or it's user group.  You do realize you have two test.txt files in two different locations right?  My apologizes my autocorrect must have done something earlier the correct command was `ls -alh` not `ls -all`

Comment: What user are you running Visual Studio code with `hellmers` or `work`?

Comment: @Ramhound Default user is `hellmers`, new user is `work`. I realize there are two different files at two different locations.

Comment: @Ramhound When logged in as `work`, I start VS Code with `code <file>`, then I cannot save the file if the permissions isn't `o+w`.

Comment: @Ramhound When logged in as `hellmers`, I start VS Code with `code <file>`, then I CAN save the file WITHOUT the `o+w` permissions.

Comment: Post your `/etc/wsl.conf` as an [edit] to your question and I will submit an answer to resolve this error

Comment: @Ramhound `/etc/wsl.conf` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/286).  Namely, VSCode always runs as the *default* user in a WSL session.

You should be able to confirm this with a simple `whoami` in the VSCode terminal.  Even though you started it from the `work` user, it will likely be running as `hellmers`.

For your particular use case, I would think, you could give your `hellmers` user access to the `work` user folder.  Seems to work for me:

```
sudo usermod -aG work hellmers
chmod -R g+wrx /home/work
```

If you really do need to run VSCode *as* the `work` user, per that Github issue, you'll need to change the *default* user for the WSL instance.  The *recommended* way of doing this is by creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` (as `sudo`) with the following contents:

```
[user]
default=work
```

Then stopping your WSL instance with `wsl --terminate <distroname` and restarting.

VSCode should run as the `work` user at that point.

It's not pretty, nor convenient.  But if you must run VSCode as a different user, you'll need to make that user the default for the WSL instance.

Another possible alternative would be to set up separate WSL instances, one with `hellmers` as the default and the other, of course, with `work`.  There's nothing wrong with keeping around multiple "utility" WSL instances as you need them.

Comment: And apologies for missing this when you posted it on Stack Overflow.  That *was* probably a better place for it, but I know you didn't get any responses there after a few days.

Comment: Don't apologies, it is not you duty to always answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, giving `hellmers` user access to the `work` user folder doesn't work.  That including setting the group access to `g+wtx`.

Comment: When opening a WSL terminal within VSCode, it does indeed show `hellmers` as the logged in one. Maybe it isn't any of the WSL users which try to save, maybe it rather is the host (Windows) user which doesn't have access. See the error since before.

Comment: By the way, VSCode runs different on this user as after running I continuously get `update#setState idle` and `update#setState checking for updates` etc and an empty `cli.js` is always opened

Comment: Running out of ideas, especially as to why VSCode's terminal would still show `hellmers` as the user when the default was changed to `work` in `/etc/wsl.conf`.  I did test this out myself before posting with a new `work` user in my instance, and it works for me :-/.  Just to confirm that you did a `wsl --terminate <distroname>`, right?  At this point, I'm wondering if something is persisted in either `/home/work/.vscode-server` or `/home/hellmers/.vscode-server`.  You might try renaming those directories and then trying again (the server component will be reinstalled).

Comment: @RobinHellmers Apologies - I just noticed (when someone upvoted this) that I didn't tag you in that last reply.  I hope that didn't cause you to miss it, but I know it's likely.  I often miss replies myself if I'm not tagged.  Did you ever have any success resolving this?

Comment: how do I know what to put for distroname??