# Launching VSCode in WSL launches in different directories depending on current directory

Tags: linux, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

In WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04):

When in the mounted `C:\` drive
  `linuxUsername@computer:/mnt/c $ code /home/linuxUsername/text.txt`
*?erroneously?* tries to open the file relative to my Windows `C:\` drive, `C:\home\linuxUsername\text.txt`.

When in the Linux FS portion 
  `linuxUsername@computer:/ $ code /home/linuxUsername/text.txt`
works properly opening the file at `/home/linuxUsername/text.txt`

**Is this the intended behaviour? If so, can I change it?**

If I wanted to open a file relative to the `C:\` drive I would use it's path `/mnt/c/Users/windowsUsername/...`

Comment: Visual Studio Code by design runs as the default user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL: Windows doesn't have permission to write new user files](https://superuser.com/questions/1677178/wsl-windows-doesnt-have-permission-to-write-new-user-files)

Comment: @Ramhound, I don't think it answers my question. `whoami` spits out the my linuxUsername from both paths.